# Add Taxonomy to Wordpress posts in bulk if post title contains text

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, taxonomy

I would like to add the Taxonomy term "Michael Jordan" to every published post that has the text "Michael Jordan" somewhere in its post title.

I assume you should be able to do this via MYSQL injections using PHPMYADMIN with the right query. However Wordpess's database tables for taxonomies and terms is a bit complicated for my level of MYSQL.

I can select all the posts from the wp_posts table with the term "Michael Jordan" using.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%Michael Jordan%';
```

I assume I would use the Post IDs from this result, to identify which posts to add the Taxonomy term.

Thank you for help with forming the right query.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a backup of your database before proceeding.

1. Find the `term_id` for your term "Michael Jordan"

`select * from wp_terms where name="Michael Jordan"` , which should give you similar output

```
| term_id | name           | slug           | term_group |
+---------+----------------+----------------+------------+
|      12 | Michael Jordan | michael-jordan |          0 |
```

Note the `term_id` (yours will be a different number)

2. And then the following query

`INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships SELECT id,term_id_noted_on_step_1,0 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%Michael Jordan%'`

Just in case you'd like to go the WordPress route, check [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

Comment: Thank you,your query seems logical, My term ID is 17, I tried: INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships SELECT id,17,0 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%Michael Jordan%'; and i got this error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '47-17' for key 'PRIMARY'  .I believe this is happening because I already have some posts with the taxonoy attached. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The error shows because some of the posts already have the term attached. In that case you can try `INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships.........`

Comment: Thank you, I did research on IGNORE , however it looked as if ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE would be safer? so INSERT wp_terms_relationships.... WHERE .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id =id; However this gave the error: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' . I am now am not sure if I should try removing the id = id or use IGNORE. What do you think?

Comment: IGNORE should work just fine, if its finds a duplicate key it will not insert the row. Besides you have a backup to fall back to :)

Comment: Thanks again, tried IGNORE, no errors, but I got : MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0255 sec)

Comment: That is quite strange, well I guess then seriously look into using `wp_set_object_terms`

Comment: I think my query is wrong, I ran:  SELECT id,17,0 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%Michael Jordan%'; without the INSERT, I got a short list of posts that have already been tagged with term id 17. I think my query selects this short list FIRST, then ignores them all. Instead of selecting all posts with "Michael Jordan" first, then adding term id 17 to the posts that don't already have it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to do some manual checking first and ensure that the posts that don't have the term, definitely have the word "Michael Jordan" in their title.

Comment: I was wrong, I got 310 results from SELECT statement,the results were paged. This leaves me trying `wp_set_object_terms` and not a MYSQL query which I want. To clarify, I would like the term "Michael Jordan" to be added to the "player" taxonomy on the resulted posts. Does this change the query? Would I put the `wp_set_object_terms` function in functions.php? Can I run by adding, then deleting code? Would this work:`<?php $post_ids = array( 6, 8  );
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_ids, michael-jordan, 'player' );
if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {Fail} else {Success}?> `

Comment: If you use the above code it will clear all existing terms on the post, to append "michael-jordan" add a 4th parameter of append `true`. See the codex for the correct syntax, also please quote the words michael-jordan.

Comment: I got it, this works: `INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships SELECT id,`  `term_taxonomy_id`  `,0 FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%Michael Jordan%';` Two things to note: I had to use the `term_taxonomy_id` and not just `term_id` because I was using a custom taxonomy. Also PHPMYADMIN does not show the amount of rows affected, even after successful Inserts, it also has to use IGNORE if there is at least one duplicate. Any ideas on showing rows affected in PHPMYADMIN after query? Also would you like to update your answer, so I can up-vote it? You have helped a lot.